# How do you stop eclipse from automatically creating JPA entities from tables?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have a JPA project in eclipse and something keeps synchronizing the DB tables with the entities. The problem is that the entities that are created end with underscore ("_.java"). I already manually created the entities from the schema, so that causes duplicate entities, then version control picks them up and wants to add them to the repo etc.

How do I tell eclipse not to generate the entities, or to generate them but without the underscore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those `xxx_.java` files are metamodel classes, and they are necessary, automatically generated by the framework and should not interfered with your work, Why do you want to delete them?

As [this site](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/metamodel.html) says:

> This metamodel is important in 2 ways.
>
> - First, it allows providers and frameworks a generic way to deal with an application's domain model.
> - Second, from an application writer's perspective, it allows very fluent expression of completely type-safe criteria queries, especially the Static Metamodel approach.

And:

> - For each managed class X in package p, a metamodel class X_ in package p is created.
> - The name of the metamodel class is derived from the name of the managed class by appending "_" to the name of the managed class.

For what you have written, everything appears to be normal. The duplicated class and the `_` are necessary for the framework and you can simply ignore them. You should read [this site](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html) too for more information.

But if you want not to add those files to your repo, there are ways to exclude certain files when you have to commit, depending on the repository system (like in git, using the `.gitignore` file).

Comment: Thanks, I got confused thinking some background process is creating entities from the DB model. I now understand this is completely different - essentially it's additional information describing the model.

Comment: So I added the _.java files to version control, but now getting files generated with two underscores (__.java). So the problem, and the question, remains, how do I turn it off?

Comment: Somehow the metadata files were added to persistence.xml thus causing the __.java files to be created.

Comment: If you don't want to generate those files every-time you delete them, you could try de-activate the "Enable Annotation Processing" flag... Go to Properties -> Java Compiler -> Annotation Processing -> Enable Annotation Processing